# What is the purpose of the "If-Modified-Since" parameter of the setRequestProperty method?

Tags: java, java-me

When we create a HttpConnection then we can call the setRequestProperty method and we can pass as its parameter ("If-Modified-Since","7 Sep 2005 19:43:31 GMT") for example.

I want to know when do we use the "If-Modified-Since" parameter , and what is its goal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The If-Modified-Since HTTP header requests that the server not bother to return the requested resource unless it has been modified since the specified date. If the resource has not been modified, a complying server would return a 304 (not modified) status instead.

See [RFC 2616](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) for details, particularly section 14.25.

Comment: To add, if the requestor has cached a previously retrieved copy of the resource then it can use the timestamp of that previous retrieval in here; if the resource has not changed since the previous retrieval then the client can interpret 304 to use the cached content and save on time and resources spent in retrieval.